# Placing tiles on 2D Simplex noise

Tags: 2d, tiles, simplex-noise

I have been experimenting with 2D Simplex noise for a mini-project and while I cannot say I understand the maths behind it, I begin to feel quite confident with how I can manipulate it to get different types of output.

While noise generation/algorithms/manipulation are quite easy to find, I am having trouble finding any good resources on the next step, i.e. placing 2D tiles based on the noise output (for the purpose of making some kind of 2D terrain).

I realize a crude and simple way would be to just loop through my array and place a tile on every coordinate where the noise value is above a certain point, but the output would look very rough, tiles would be overlapping each other, etc.

Does anyone have any good resources or information to share on this subject?

Thanks,

Comment: Here's a useful [starting point](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79049/generating-tile-map) from this site. And a question with a [more detailed answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/random-map-generation). Such questions on procedural tilemap generation have been asked several times before.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the information I'm after is out there, it's just hard to know what to search for.